# Compiled CSS is not being attached to JSX in react build

Tags: reactjs, webpack, css-loader

I am currently attempting to test the first build of my react application. All my .scss looks great in dev, however, when I build for production none of my styling is added to the jsx, unless I use :local(my-css) around every item.

for the boilerplate of the application, I used create-react-app. All the dependencies are listed in the package.json below. so far, I have tried messing with my webpack.config.prod.js to change various options for all the loaders. Among this, I have tried setting sourceMap to true and false in the css-loader options, and tried minimizing the scss config to just:

```
    test: /\.scss/,
    loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader'
```

I have also tried removing the postcss-loader with no success. I have searched so many different sites trying to figure out a solution, that I ran out of articles written in English and had to translate the pages from various languages.

One other relevant thing to note is that the scss is compiled into css and added to a main.css file. main.map.css also contains the correct mappings for files. There are also .css files for every component present that contain non-minified versions of the compiled css. Image to illustrate this:

[image: Screenshots from Sources]

Prod Webpack Config:

```
{
            test: /\.css$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract(
              Object.assign(

                {

                  fallback: {
                    loader: require.resolve('style-loader'),
                    options: {
                      hmr: false,
                      modules: true,
                      localIdentName: '[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]'
                    },
                  },

                  use: [
                    {
                      loader: require.resolve('css-loader'),
                      options: {
                        importLoaders: 1,
                        minimize: true,
                        sourceMap: shouldUseSourceMap,
                      },
                    },
                    {
                      loader: require.resolve('postcss-loader'),
                      options: {
                        // Necessary for external CSS imports to work
                        // https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/2677
                        ident: 'postcss',
                        plugins: () => [
                          require('postcss-flexbugs-fixes'),
                          autoprefixer({
                            browsers: [
                              '>1%',
                              'last 4 versions',
                              'Firefox ESR',
                              'not ie < 9', // React doesn't support IE8 anyway
                            ],
                            flexbox: 'no-2009',                              
}),
                        ],
                      },
                    },
                  ],
                },
                extractTextPluginOptions
              )
            ),

          },
          {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract(
              Object.assign(

                {

                  fallback: {
                    loader: require.resolve('style-loader'),
                    options: {
                      hmr: false,
                      modules: true,
                      localIdentName: '[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]'
                    },
                  },

                  use: [
                    {
                      loader: require.resolve('css-loader'),
                      options: {
                        importLoaders: 1,
                        minimize: true,
                        sourceMap: shouldUseSourceMap,
                      },
                    },
                    {
                      loader: require.resolve('postcss-loader'),
                      options: {
                        // Necessary for external CSS imports to work
                        // https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/2677
                       ident: 'postcss',
                        plugins: () => [
                          require('postcss-flexbugs-fixes'),
                          autoprefixer({
                            browsers: [
                              '>1%',
                              'last 4 versions',
                              'Firefox ESR',
                              'not ie < 9', // React doesn't support IE8 anyway
                            ],
                            flexbox: 'no-2009',
                          }),
                        ],
                      },
                    },
                    {
                      loader: 'sass-loader',
                    },
                  ],
                },
                extractTextPluginOptions
              )
            ),
            // Note: this won't work without `new ExtractTextPlugin()` in `plugins`.
          },
```

package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
     "@babel/core": "^7.2.2",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.2.3",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.2.0",
    "@kennethormandy/react-fittext": "^0.5.1",
    "ajv": "^6.6.2",
    "autoprefixer": "7.1.6",
    "axiom": "^0.1.6",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^9.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^23.4.2",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
    "babel-plugin-react-css-modules": "^5.0.0",
    "babel-preset-react-app": "^6.1.0",
    "case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin": "2.1.1",
    "chalk": "1.1.3",
    "css-loader": "0.28.7",
    "dotenv": "4.0.0",
    "dotenv-expand": "4.2.0",
    "eslint": "4.10.0",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^2.1.0",
    "eslint-loader": "1.9.0",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "2.39.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "5.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.4.0",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.11",
    "fs-extra": "3.0.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "2.29.0",
    "imagemin": "^5.3.1",
    "img-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "jest": "20.0.4",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "moment": "^2.23.0",
    "object-assign": "4.1.1",
    "postcss-flexbugs-fixes": "3.2.0",
    "postcss-loader": "2.0.8",
    "postcss-scss": "^2.0.0",
    "promise": "8.0.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.2",
    "proptypes": "^1.1.0",
    "raf": "3.4.0",
    "react": "^16.7.0",
    "react-big-calendar": "^0.20.2",
    "react-dev-utils": "^5.0.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.7.0",
    "react-google-login": "^4.0.1",
    "react-icons": "^2.2.7",
    "react-input-mask": "^2.0.4",
    "react-linkify": "^0.2.2",
    "react-redux": "^5.1.1",
    "react-router": "^4.3.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-textarea-autosize": "^7.1.0",
    "react-transition-group": "^2.5.2",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-axios-middleware": "^4.0.0",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-persist": "^5.10.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "resolve": "1.6.0",
    "style-loader": "0.19.0",
    "sw-precache-webpack-plugin": "0.11.4",
    "url-loader": "^0.6.2",
    "webpack": "3.8.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "2.9.4",
    "webpack-manifest-plugin": "1.3.2",
    "whatwg-fetch": "2.0.3"
  },
"devDependencies": {
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.11.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "sass": "*"
  }
```

The only thing that seems to work is if I wrap every item in every scss file in :local(). This is not a satisfactory option, as I wish to know what is wrong with my config so I can avoid it in the future. Also, I would have to go and manually change hundreds of items which does not sound like a good time. Any insight on how to tackle this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: how are you assigning the css/classes in your components. if you are using css modules (:local) then you have to import the class names. if you are using :global you need to assign the class names as strings like you do in regular html. there should be something like `className='FormCSS'` in your jsx

Comment: @AndrewAxton I am using css modules. so, for example, with the wrapper I have className={classes.wrapper} where classes is my import for the .scss file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem. Turns out you need to enable modules in 'css-loader' like so:

```
{
    loader: require.resolve('css-loader'),
    options: {
        modules: true //must add this
        importLoaders: 1,
        minimize: true,
        sourceMap: shouldUseSourceMap,
    },
},
```

Comment: Could you specify the file name this change was made in?